# AttributeError: Tuple object has no attribute move(OOP)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pygame, attributeerror

I've tried to run the code as normal, however I was met with a error which looks something like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Coursework assets\gametest1.py", line 85, in <module>
    wizard.move(wizard.x)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'move'
```

Below is the class for the original player Player class for the main character. Where the error may have originated from

```
class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.standing = True
        self.left = False
        self.right = True
        self.vel = 15
    def move(self,x,y):
        if not(self.standing):
            if k[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.x  > 0 - 150:
                self.left = True
                self.right = False            
                self.x -= self.vel
            elif k[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.x  < 500 - 150 :
                self.right = True
                self.left = False
                self.x += self.vel
        else:
            self.standing = True
   run = True
```

Main game loop

```
wizard = (25,420)
while run:#main game loop
    pygame.time.delay(15)
    wizard.move(wizard.x,wizard.y)
    win.blit(bg,(0,0))
    wizard.jump(wizard.y)
    wizard.draw(win)) 
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I am deeply puzzled as to what your variable  'wizard' is supposed to be! You have assigned a tuple to it but you appear to be trying to treat it as an instance of your player class! Do you mean to set up a player called wizard? In which case you need to replace the first line of your game loop with 'wizard = player(45,420)'

Answer (score 2):

In the game loop, the wizard you create is just a tuple. Create it as `wizard = player(25, 420)`

Also, it is heavily recommended to make class names capital (`Player`). See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more coding style recommendations which are generally accepted by Python community.

Moreover, you don't have to put parentheses around the negated statement, just as `if not self.standing`. And you probably actually don't want the `not` there, you want to move the wizard if he is standing, and raise him when he isn't...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your wizard is meant to be "player" class, the deceleration of the variable `wizard` is not correct.

The code has:

```
wizard = (25,420)
```

Which just makes the wizard a pair of numbers. ( Known as a "tuple ).

I think this should be an *instance* of `player`, with the `x` and `y` parameters of 25, 240 ~

```
wizard = player( 25, 420 )
```

I assume you left the functions `player.jump()` and `player.draw()` out of the code, but if they are not written yet, your main loop will break with much the same error you already reported, except for `.jump()` first.